# Creating default values object

Tags: solidity, ether, ethers.js, ethereumjs, smart-contract-wallets

I basically want to build something like

```
const levelMappings = {
   0: 'BASIC',
   500: 'REGULAR',
   5000: 'PREMIUM'
}
```

I've tried creating an enum for basic premium and regular

```
enum Levels { BASIC, REGULAR, PREMIUM, ELITE }
```

and i guess i could use some if statements and hard code them numbers into the if statements. But i need to be able to change the levels quite easily as this is essentially a Contract Factory.

I basically just want to be able to call a function that returns the level information stuff, maybe even in the future move the level code from js to the contract its-self i just struggle with key value data storing.

Comment: I'm trying to understand you issue, so you want to write a factory that will deploy the same contract but the enum could be different each time. Is that correct?

Comment: No from within the contract i want to be able to check a members balance which is another uint balance (in memory) so so yeah level has a number related to it. I want to perform some maths to check which level from that unum is there i know how to do the math bit in solidity but i want to associate that enum with their relative values from the js object

Answer (score 0):

@nathan Nesadill , Enum's in solidity returns value as per their index.
for example : In `enum Levels { BASIC, REGULAR, PREMIUM, ELITE }` if you check `Levels.BASIC` the result is `0` , if you check `Levels.ELITE` the result is `3`.

example:-

```
contract MyContract {
    string[] levelMappings = [ 'BASIC','REGULAR','PREMIUM', 'ELITE' ];
    enum Levels { BASIC, REGULAR, PREMIUM, ELITE }
    
    string public currentLevel;
    
    constructor() {  // initialize with minimal level
        currentLevel = levelMappings[Levels.BASIC]; 
    }
    
    // update level by passing a value
    function updateLevel(uint256 _val) public {
     if(_val == 0){
        currentLevel = levelMappings[Levels.BASIC];
     }
     if(_val == 500){
        currentLevel = levelMappings[Levels.REGULAR];
     }
     if(_val == 5000){
        currentLevel = levelMappings[Levels.PREMIUM];
     }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have the feeling this is what OP tries to avoid (hardcoding 0/500/5000). Perhaps having an update level taking an array of uint would solve what OP is asking (ie updating the whole mapping, using the enum as keys)?